# Replace a view with the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

I have a view as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_entry_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="4dp" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quick_response_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/quick_response_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="104dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have about 20 items in the `recyclerview`.

Now when the user clicks on the edit text the Keyboard comes up, I want it to behave in such a way that the keyboard replaces the `RecyclerView`, that it goes out of view when the keyboard comes up and then comes back in when the keyboard is dismissed.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to show the keyboard while

```
  @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    private void showKeyboard() {
       rv.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
        ((InputMethodManager) messageEditText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(messageEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
```

In keyboard add click event for the done button or enter button to enable the RecyclerView again.

Comment: I plugged this code, it works but there is a slight delay between the disappearance of the rv and the appearance of the keyboard. Any idea how to avoid that?